# FlowGear Droppoint error

Tags: flowgear

I'm getting the following error when trying to Test a SQL connection via a droppoint:

> DropPoint Invoke Error: Unable to instance node SqlQuery 2.1.0.6:
>   Decryption failed: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that either the transport or the stored Node at the DropPoint is corrupt. A DropPoint restart should resolve this but it's strongly recommended that you upgrade to the new WebSockets-based DropPoints which can be downloaded from the Console. More at https://developers.flowgear.net/kb/DropPoint

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've just downloaded the droppoint installed from the console, and the version installed is still v3.1.  Not v4.  How do I get v4 installer?

Comment: The current verison in the Console is V4. Did you uninstall it from Control Panel first?

Comment: Yup.  I see I'm being confused by the Console listing my droppoints...it still reports v3.1  However, if I use the File Properties Dialog in Windows, on the actual EXE, I see it is v4.

Comment: Re-register it from the DropPoint UI, this causes the service to restart and you should then see the verison in the Console updating